# AngularJS debounce not working as intended

Tags: javascript, angularjs, observable

I needed to go back to AngularJS project I made a long time ago (what a pain if you have gotten deep into Angular 2). I need to replace a search bar input by using debounce on the model change as we have much more traffic than we did back then. It was okay to send a request on each keystroke but this is unacceptable with the number of visitors we have now.

In Angular 2, rxjs' debounce would solve my problem, but in AngularJS it is not working as intended. Although this bug is not crucial to my workflow, I'm just curious whether this is indeed the intended behaviour.

In rxjs, what debounces would do is:

```
User interactions(keystrokes, each dash represents 100ms)
1--2---3----4-5-6-7----8-----9-----
1----2----3----5----7----8----9----
^ .debounceTime(500)
```

As you can see, action 4 and 6 will be ignored as they will get replaced by the action triggered after them (in a 500ms timespan).

But in AngularJS, using `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }"`, I get:

```
User interactions(keystrokes, each dash represents 100ms)
1--2---3----4-5-6-7----8-----9-----
1----------------------8-----9-----
^ AngularJS
```

In this example, AngularJS only picks up changes whenever there is 500ms of nothingness. The duration in between action 1 - 8 are less than 500ms, so the changes during that duration never gets updated. Is this the intended behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debounce timer will be reset each time the user changes the input. [From the Angular docs:](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/docs/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

> The updateOn and debounce properties allow you to specify a custom list of events that will trigger a model update and/or a debouncing delay so that the actual update only takes place when a timer expires; **this timer will be reset after another change takes place**.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was just curious whether the AngularJS' or rxjs' debounce method is the more appropriate behaviour. What do you think? Do you think it should behave as in graph 1 or 2 I provided in the question?

Comment: I think it generally makes more sense to wait for the user to finish writing what he/she wants before making a call, so I think the Angular approach is appropriate.

Comment: After doing a bit more research I found something that backs up your opinion: The definition of debouncing: "Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for N milliseconds.". Thanks for the info!